# How can I generate a fishnet grid and a matrix of percentage of overlapping in R?

Tags: raster, r, vector-grid, polygonize

I'm trying use R for create a fishnet grid like in arcGIS with many cells of same size.

In the arcGIS 9.3 we have the option of create a polygon with many small square polygons (eg. 1 x 1 degree of lat and long) in the extent of our study area using the tool 'create fishnet' (http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=Create_Fishnet_(Data_Management)) and after aply the tool 'Feature to Polygon' to transform the polygon lines in square polygons. Other option is use the “Hawth’s Tools” extension and acess the “Sampling Tools” -> “Create Vector Grid (line/polygon) but the extension only work properly until arcGIS 9.2.

Then I want create the fishnet grid (polygon with many regular squares) and after calculate many percentage of overlap of some polygons to each cell of the fishnet and create a matrix with each cell in lines and each polygon in the columns, like this [matrix](https://www.dropbox.com/s/lxlqkhur3fyl5v9/Matrix.PNG).

Comment: What's a 'fishnet grid'? Is it lines? Or small square polygons? Or a raster? What do you want to do with it when you've got it?

Comment: Sorry, I edited the post to be more clear. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I found a really simple and good solution with the rasterize function from raster package

```
library(raster)
library(sp)
```

> Create polygons

```
x_coord <- c(0,  1,  6, 4, 2)
y_coord <- c(10, 5, 5, 12, 10)
xym <- cbind(x_coord, y_coord)
p1 = Polygon(xym)
p2 = Polygon(xym - 3)
ps1 = Polygons(list(p1), 1)
ps2 = Polygons(list(p2), 2)
sps = SpatialPolygons(list(ps1, ps2))
proj4string(sps) = CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0")
```

> Create a SpatialPolygonsDataFrame

```
spdf = SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(sps, data.frame(col1 = 1:2))
```

> Create a raster of the study area

```
fishnet.r <- raster(extent(spdf)+5)
res(fishnet.r) <- 2
proj4string(fishnet.r) <- CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0")
```

> check the inputs

```
fishnet <- rasterToPolygons(fishnet.r)
plot(fishnet)
plot(spdf, col = 1:2, add = T)
```

[image]

> Get the percentage cover of polygons for all cells

```
l <- vector('list', length(spdf))
for(i in 1:length(spdf)) {
  l[[i]] <- rasterize(spdf[i, ], fishnet.r, getCover = TRUE)
}
b <- brick(l)
plot(b)
```

[image]

> Get the percentage in matrix format

```
m.out <- as.matrix(b)
```

> Transform from RasterBrick to polygon (fishnet)

```
fishnet.out <- rasterToPolygons(b)
```

Answer (score 3):

If you mean by fishnet grid a regular spatial grid, there are several options available in R:

- Simply use a matrix.
- Use the SpatialGrid/Pixels classes from the sp package
- Use the raster format from the raster package.

A good overview of spatial packages in R is given on the [CRAN Spatial Task View](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Spatial.html).

Answer (score 1):

The [sp](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sp/sp.pdf) package in R might be a good place to start. A quick browse through the pdf manual shows that there are functions with names such as `gridlines` that might be useful to you.

Answer (score 0):

a good and fast way to start is to create your fishnet using the `raster` package to create your grid as a raster and then transform it into a polygon.

```
library(raster)
fishnet <- raster() # this creates a raster with the extent of the whole world.
res(fishnet) <- .5  # sets the resolution of your grid -- here .5 x .5 degrees
crs(fishnet) <- CRS("+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84") # set projection
fishnet <- rasterToPolygons(fishnet) # transform into a polygon
fishnet@data <- data.frame(id = 1:nrow(fishnet)) # assigning some data
```

then you might select the polygons (cells) which overlap with your other polygon with

```
fishnet <- fishnet[!is.na(over(fishnet, polygon))[,1],]
```

finally, to calculate the percentage of the area that the polygon covers of each cell, you might try using brute force and loop over all your cells to calculate the relative area of the intersection of each cell with your polygon. I propose the package `rgeos` for the task

```
library(rgeos)
for (i in 1:nrow(fishnet)) {
  fishnet[i,]$share <- gArea(gIntersects(polygon, fishnet[i,]))/gArea(fishnet[i,])
}
```

Comment: Bruno Conte Leite, thanks for contribute, but your example did not works for me. I posted a solution really simple, but you could try use my "spdf" object example to try apply in your solution and fix it. I think it will be good to explore other options.